# How to manage settings on an Android device remotely

Tags: settings, remote-control, default-applications, remote-access

I need to manage an Android device remotely. It is a tablet running Android 6.0 used by an elderly person, which alters the setting from time to time. (Or maybe the person does, who knows). I live very far away and need to manage this device remotely.
- check if WiFi is on and if not, turn Wifi on (already found an app for that)
- check if the location service is on and if not, turn it on
- restore the default launcher
- restore the Default keyboard

The device uses a slow mobile connection, so remote-desktoop as VNC/Temviewer is a no-go. Despite that, I do not want to manage the device over remote desktop, i only need to check the settings and alter them remotely.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Related: [Remote login into the phone from a PC](/q/4251/16575) and a bunch of [questions tagged remote-control](/questions/tagged/remote-access?sort=frequent). Have you checked with any of those?

Comment: Remote management of a device without UI is the typical task of an Mobile Device Management (MDM) system. Unfortunately most of the are only for enterprise usage. A few are designed for parents who want to control their children's device - which is IMHO a lot closer to what you are searching.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en). Which can be bit difficult to work with for you, if you're not familiar with it. but it's worth learning for your use case. You can make profiles which will get triggered when particular conditions are met. For example, you can start the wifi or turn your phone into silent mode when it's within 100mts of your home, or you can change the default launcher according to your needs in the question. [Here](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-use-tasker-199872/) you can find basic tutorial for Tasker, which can help you learn more about it.
For your particular use case I found some profiles which can help you,

1) [Restore Default Launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110106/dynamic-launcher-with-tasker)

2) [Restore Default Keyboard](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-automatically-change-your-keyboard-on-a-per-app-basis/)

3) [These are other profiles, you can look into](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/tasker-101-5-useful-profiles-help-get-you-started-with-android-automation-0163529/).

Since you can not root your tablet, these are the [use cases](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/5gsgvp/the_best_tasker_profiles_nonroot/dav3lug/?st=je7f6001&sh=191cdc22) for the profiles you can use/create without root. (These are just for your knowledge, because Tasker can do lots of stuffs even without root. Which can come handy in some other scenario you want to use in future)

**Some ADB Commands I found which can help you**,

1) [Change the default Keyboard using ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253983/change-the-default-android-keyboard-using-adb-or-java-code)

2) [Enable Location services On or off](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114033/167921)

**To connect using ADB remotely, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1921481) can help you**

The answers in the question above is not using adb shell su, so I'm assuming it will work on non rooted phones aswell (You already found answer for other use cases you mentioned in your question, So hopefully this solves your question).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely try the tasker app. the I do not want to disable the default launcher and  I can not root the device but there might be other way using the _adb_ - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922386/1991697

Comment: Ohh yes, you can use adb to perform the same task. But tasker just gives you an added benefit to automate everything. So if you want to create your own profile to change to default launcher as soon as other is selected, you can do it. So just automating the whole process is the added benefit with tasker.

Comment: ADB over TCP is an insecure protocol and should not be exposed to the Internet. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25902/how-to-connect-adb-over-3g-4g

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried airdroid https://www.airdroid.com/ but it does not give you full access to the tablet settings to get that you need something like https://www.logmein.com/ i think it will work with a slow internet connection

I hope my answer was helpful